# QTMovie opened movie successfully?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there any way to detect whether QTMovie successfully loaded a movie? I.E. whether a valid component is found?

Or even better enumerate the components on launch and detect then what components have been loaded without having to provide a sample movie?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read the [QTMovie API reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovie_Class/Reference/Reference.html)? When you try to create a QTMovie object, you'll get either a valid movie object or nil. If you make use of the NSError argument (that's included on all the initializers/factory methods that create movies from files/URLs), you'll even get an explanation of what went wrong if the method returns nil. Also in that reference (handily categorized in the Tasks section), are a number of ways to get pretty much any information about the movie you want.

Regarding the "components" part of your question, I don't think QTKit gives you access to this directly. You might have to use the QuickTime.framework and dive deeper. You *might* be able to figure out whether your third-party-supported file type is actually supported by using the +[QTMovie movieFileTypes:] method (also found in the API reference I linked) and seeing if your file's extension appears there.

Comment: I have read extensively the QTMovie API.

The problem I'm having is not whether QT can open the filetype (it's an avi) but whether it can decompress the file (it's been encoded with DivX).

Due to this it will show the avi file type as supported and create the movie object with a valid pointer but when it comes to play back the frames will not display.  
I guess there might be something deeper the the QuickTime.framework but I'm  fairly new at this and don't really know where to look beyond the API reference.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't clear from your question. I don't believe QuickTime supports all AVI formats (there are differences) natively. I think you have to rely on a plug-in and unfortunately there's no access in QTKit (and I don't recall anything in QuickTime.framework) that gives you access to that much detail about supported codecs.

Comment: Oh, that's a shame. It's frustrating that QTMovie returns a valid object even when it can't necessarily play the file. I might try and enumerate the QTTracks inside the movie and see if a video track exists, that is the only thing I can think to do. Thanks anyway.